# Switch view when press button

Tags: ios, view, uibutton

I want to change view when I press a button.
in the root view .h i have this:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)switchToMap;

@end
```

and in the .m I have this:

```
-(IBAction)switchToMap
{
    CustomViewController *customViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CustomViewController" bundle:nil];
    customViewController.title = @"Mappa";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:customViewController animated:YES];
    //[self.view addSubview:customViewController.view];
}
```

the code doesn't work, but if I use the second method `[self.view addSubview:customViewController.view];`works, and I don't know why.

Comment: make sure you have MainViewController in navigationController using with  iniitWithRootViewController

Comment: Because there is no navigation controller available, instead of that present the view as a modal view, it'll work

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have `UINavigationController` as your `rootViewController`.

**AppDelegate.m**

```
UINavigationController *navigation=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainVC];
self.window.rootViewController=navigation;
```

Answer (score 0):

try doing this:

```
ViewController *CustomViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];    
[self presentViewController:CustomViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: providing some explanation to your answer will likely benefit OP and others